# finding differences with tar

Tags: python, shell, tar

I use such script for application upgrade:

```
#!/bin/sh
tar fUxz data.tar.gz --overwrite
tar fd data.tar.gz >$0.diff
if [ -s $0.diff ]
then
  mv $0.diff $0.out
else
  echo "ok" >$0.out
fi
```

I want to have in *.out file some error message in case if extraction/overwrite is failed.
in my dir there was the file f1.lms:

```
-rw-r--r--+  1 user1 wheel    27777 Jun 16  2010 f1.lms
```

after script run:

```
-rw-r--r--+  1 user1 wheel    27777 Mar 20 14:29 f1.lms
```

And I got such message in .out:

```
f1.lms: Mode differs
f1.lms: Uid differs
f1.lms: Gid differs
```

What's the reason - does that mean extraction was failed? What should I do to get "ok"?

But when I call this script from my python script (pexpect) I got another message:

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Archive contains obsolescent base-64 headers
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

I can see files are extracted but there is no warnings "Mode/.. differs" - looks like diff command doesn't work.

How to make this script working - both simply as shell script and from the python?

Comment: I think you should try to isolate the problem.

Comment: Pass the `z` flag to `tar fd`